# ClassNotFoundException in Android Instrumentation test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am trying to write instrumentation test for my app but I have been getting this error. I have looked at almost all the answer present in the internet but none is working for me.

I have attached my gradle file and tests here for reference

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.vuclip.viu.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.myapp, PID: 1228
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.vuclip.viu.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5746)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1664)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.instantiate(ActivityThread.java:6497)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
```

**build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../jacoco-core.gradle'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion buildVersion.targetSdk
    buildToolsVersion buildVersion.buildTools

    baseFeature true
//    testBuildType "release"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion buildVersion.minSdk
        //do not increment this version, <21 fixes white notif icon issue on lollypop

        targetSdkVersion buildVersion.targetSdk
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.02"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    /*aaptOptios {
        additionalParameters '--utf16'
    }*/

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }


    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }


    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
    }

}


dependencies {
    //other dependencies

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.10.0'
}
```

Can anyone share some light into this ?

Comment: did you have added the dependency for jUnit already?

Comment: yes JUnit dependency is there.

Comment: i can't find it in your dependency closure. In my project I implemented jUnit like so: `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`